# Binary Search Tree reading in Strings? C++

Tags: c++, string, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I have a project that is due Monday night. The project is to implement a Red Black Tree that reads in the declaration of Independence as "Independence.txt" and puts those strings into a red black tree. I am trying to implement it as a Binary Search Tree first and then will add the colors and the rotations as I already have that code worked out.

The problem I am facing is that right now I keep getting the following errors: "error C2660" 'RBT ::Insert': function does not take 1 arguments" and "IntelliSense: non suitable conversion function from "std:string" to "RBT::RBTNode *" exists" and then IntelliSense: too few arguments in function call which points to the line root.Insert(myString);

I also need help with reading in the file into the binary search tree. I do think my insert method is correct, and the problem lies in the main method.

Thanks for any help as I am stuck.

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std; 

template<typename T>
class RBT
{
    struct RBTNode {
        T data;
        RBTNode* left;
        RBTNode* right;
    };

public:
    RBT();
    ~RBT();
    void GetNewNode(RBTNode* root, T data);
    void Insert(RBTNode* root, T data);
    bool Search();
    void Display();

};


template <typename T>
void RBT<T>::GetNewNode(RBTNode* root, T data) {
    RBTNode* newNode = new RBTNode();
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

template <typename T>
void RBT<T>::Insert(RBTNode* root, T data) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = GetNewNode(data);
    }
    else if (data <= root->data) {
        root->left = Insert(root->left, data);
    }
    else {
        root->right = Insert(root->right, data);
    }
    return root;
} 

template<typename T>
bool RBT<T>::Search() {
    if (root == NULL) return false;
    else if (root->data == data) return true;
    else if (data <= root->data) return Search(root->left, data);
    else return Search(root->right, data);
}

template<typename T>
void RBT<T>::Display() {
    if (root->left != NULL)
        display(root->left);
    cout << root->left << endl;

    if (root->right != NULL)
        Display(root->right);
    cout << root->right << endl;
}



int main()
{
    RBT<string> root;
    string myString; 
    ifstream infile; 
    infile.open("Independence.txt"); 
    while (infile)
    {
        infile >> myString; 
        root.Insert(myString); 
    }

    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: RBTNode* newNode = new BstNode();

Answer (score 2):

Your `Insert` method takes 2 arguments (the root to insert into and the data to be inserted); in `main`, you are calling it with just 1 (the data).

Comment: What would I put into the method call from main? RBTNode* root or just root? I've tried both and getting the error message "error C2664: 'void RBT<std::string>::Insert (RBT<std::string>::RBTNode*,T)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'RBT<std::string>' to 'RBT<std::string>::RBTNode *'

Comment: `RBTNode` is internal to your class, so it sounds like you need an extra version of `Insert` which can be called from outside the class which can then, in turn, call your current `Insert` with the appropriate `RBTNode`.

Comment: Now I am getting "error C224: 'RBT <T>::Insert': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration" Any ideas? I am trying to research that problem and see what it gives me

Comment: Given that you have supplied no new code to comment on: no new ideas.

Comment: I updated the code up top. I changed the issue that schwer pointed out and then made changes with the Insert function and under the public: area in class RBT.

Comment: Your new `Insert` expects a `const String`, but that's not what you are sending it.

Comment: I changed the code again and now I am getting "error C2660: 'RBT <std::string>::Insert': function does not take 1 arguments" and "IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "RBT<std::string>::RBTNode *" exists." I know that one of the problems is that I am not taking in enough arguments to the call of Insert in main, but I am not sure what else to call.